# Style components "as" Next Link and pass down all the props to the parent

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components

I tried to create a simple styled component that can behave as both a link and a button. I wanted it so that if the href is not undefined, the component behaves as a Next Link. It works as expected and runs well. However, the problem is that the attributes from Next Link are not available to the component. For example, when I tried to add the target prop, TypeScript said it's not available for this component.

**Types**

```
import { Url } from "next/dist/shared/lib/router/router";
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";

export interface IButtonProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  href?: Url;
}
```

**Button Component**

```
"use client"

import { memo } from 'react'
import { ButtonStyled } from "./Button.styled"
import { IButtonProps } from './Button.types'
import Link from 'next/link'

export const Button = ({ href, ...props }: IButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <ButtonStyled href={href} as={href ? Link : "button"} {...props}>

    </ButtonStyled>
  )
}

export default memo(Button)
```

`<Button target="_blank" href="/dd">Button Link</Button>`

`"Type '{ children: string; target: string; href: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IButtonProps'. Property 'target' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IButtonProps'.ts(2322) (property) target: string"`

**expected**

```
export const Button = ({ href, ...props }: IButtonProps <-- *the props here can automatically be a LinkProps type when href set*) => {}
```

I wanted the Button to automatically have a Link attribute within it if the href prop is set. Thank you in advance